# What is the difference between collection and model in Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js

I am really new in Backbone.js and I would like to know the main difference.

I'm wondering if is possible to use Backbone.js for local storage?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A collection is a list (collection) of models
2. Look at https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage

Comment: So I can consider a model as field in a table and a Collections as a table. is correct this comparation?

Comment: more like a if a model is a database record (row) them a collection is a record set (or a complete table).